# Participate in session from XHR request in third party page

Tags: jquery, http, cookies, cross-domain

I have an app at foo.com that serves javascript for a "plugin" widget and successfully receives and responds to JSON API requests from the script. The script is served from foo.com, but is embedded into bar.com.

The JSON API, plugin script and JSESSIONID cookie are all 1st party from foo.com, the execution context is 3rd party, bar.com.

**Question:** My problem is that the foo.com JSESSIONID is not sent back to the server, so the plugin script (from foo.com) always gets a new session and cannot be maintained as logged into foo.com.

I'm grateful for any help to get the JSESSIONID sent back to foo.com.

**Some details:**

jQuery is served from bar.com and is used by the script at foo.com to send the requests.

On my development rig, foo.com and bar.com run on separate non-standard ports (84 and 8080).

The same origin policy would appear to apply, in general, and Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set on foo.com to * to allow bar.com to hit foo.com.

Nither bar.com or even the script from foo.com need to read the cookie, as long as HTTP requests from the plugin contain the JSESSIONID.

Comment: Please, make sure that your server at `foo.com` does not set `HttpOnly` attribute for cookies.

Comment: Just name, value and path.